# Filtering dates to within 7 days

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a working date filter that accepts a date string like `2018-02-09T19:35:54+00:00` and orders events by date.  I would like my filter to only push items in the next 7 days. I feel like I have a basic arithmetic error in my code.

```
function dashCalDateFilter() {
  return function(collection, key) {
      let output    = [];
      let keys      = [];
      let sevenDays = Date.now() + 604800000;

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
        var ikey = item[key];
        if (keys.indexOf(ikey) === -1) {
          keys.push(ikey);
          item['isFirst'] = true;
        }
        console.log(item.start_time);
        if (Date.now() - Date.parse(item.start_time) < sevenDays){
          output.push(item);
        };
      });
      return output;
    };
}
export default dashCalDateFilter;
```

Comment: Would suggest using momentjs or possibly look into datefn libraries to help smooth out differences in how various browsers will parse the date (and timezone or not).

Answer (score 0):

My math was a bit off.  Here is the working version

```
function dashCalDateFilter() {
  return function(collection, key) {
      let output    = [];
      let keys      = [];
      let sevenDays = 604800000;

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
        var ikey = item[key];
        if (keys.indexOf(ikey) === -1) {
          keys.push(ikey);
          item['isFirst'] = true;
        }
        if ((Date.parse(item.start_time) - Date.now()) < 604800000){
          output.push(item);
        } else {
          console.log('in >7 days');
          console.log(Date.parse(item.start_time) - Date.now());
        };
      });
      return output;
    };
}
export default dashCalDateFilter;
```